# Ace editor set value at current line

Tags: ace-editor

I have an issue with the Ace editor. Whenever I insert a value via editor.setValue(val) it gets inserted at the bottom of the document. Is there any way to insert the value at the current line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to insert a line use

```
editor.session.insert({row: 1, column: 0}, "text\n")
```

and to replace a line use

```
var Range = require("ace/range").Range // ace.require in no-conflict mode
editor.session.replace(new Range(1, 0, 1, Number.MAX_VALUE), "text")
```

or

```
editor.session.replace({
    start: {row: 1, column: 0},
    end: {row: 1, column: Number.MAX_VALUE}
}, "text")
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! What I wanted was the insert along with row and column. Cheers!